# Cannot fix or remove 4 dll files

Tags: dll

I am learning computer repairing and now I have installed Windows 10 to a Dell 620 in order to learn about fixing DLL errors.

My problem is that I can not fix 4 DLL errors:
[image: http://i65.tinypic.com/o6zgcj.jpg]

I used `for %1 in (*dll) do regsvr32 %1 /s` and `for %1 in (*ocx) do regsvr32 %1 /s` on the command prompt as well as `sfc /scannow`. I've reset Windows, keeping programs and documents, but nothing works. I even can't remove these items with  the `Regdllview` program.

I have no more ideas.

I have searched from internet and it seems that those are Windows os files. But why can not Windows replace or fix them?

Win 10 is fresh install from USB stick.

Comment: What problem do these DLL errors cause? What software doesn't work because of them?  Do they even *need* replacing? Tell us what the *problem* is as well as the symptoms.

Comment: Based on the screenshot, the files in question marked in red, do not exist on your system.  Which means you could if you wanted, find the registry entry for those files, and simply delete them.  Of course, removing the enteries doesn't do anything helpful, unless you also have an application that isn't working because those dlls are not registered and/or missing when the system first logs into your user.  Which in that case, easier to prevent the application from starting, then removing an entry that is harmless.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to write that there are no problems. I just installed win10 and maybe have not found those programs that use those dll files. I just have "bad feeling" that there are some missing files in my computer that could  make problems in future if i cant replace/fix them. Is it somehow possible to know what program uses those files? I thought that when computer is clean installed then there should be no missing files. Am i wrong?  I like to get to the root couse of the problem and learn how to fix it. I should know the program that uses those files, but i have no idea...